# How to use 2 storyboards for different screen sizes?

Tags: xcode, ios7

What and where do I put code for two storyboards one if they are running on a 3.5" screen and one for a 4" screen. I have two storyboards. One is named Main.storyboard and the other one is named Main2.storyboard.

Comment: You could use AutoLayout?

Comment: I can't but there's no reason to explain it can someone just tell me how to use two storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

The code goes into the AppDelegate.m file and looks similar to this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AlternateStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainstoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    return YES;
}
```

You'll need to check the screen size first, of course, see the docs for UIScreen.

Comment: Do I include the .storyboard in the @""?

Comment: In my case the storyboard file was 'AlternateStoryboard.storyboard' so no need for a .storyboard in the @""

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help. In your AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone 
       && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0) {

        //is 4 inch screen
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    }
    else {
        //is 3.5 inch screen
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main2" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The `if/else` statement checks the screen size and loads the appropriate storyboard.